# Apache Nutch perks

Tags: java, hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I came across this very big tool and before diving deep into some *not so pretty* documentations and/or buying an [ebook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HK3VPCC) : I just wanted to ask :

How does Apache Nutch handle javascript heavy sites, AND how does it fetch pages?
I mean : how does it overcome IP bans?

Comment: awful documentations ?

Comment: hey, sorry for that :) It is just I have read some more illustrative and practical books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript - there is a Selenium-based protocol implementation, this can help with JS sites

Nutch is based on Hadoop and so is batch-driven. If you are after a stream based crawling framework then [StormCrawler](http://digitalpebble.com/storm-crawler/) would be a better tool.